# current and voltage sensors for the raspberry pi

Tags: pi-2

I am working on an I-V tracer project for plotting the I-V characteristics of the solar panel in the display and i want to ask about a voltage sensor and a current sensor for the raspberry pi. I am looking for a voltage and current sensors that can accurately work with the raspberry pi and give me accurate readings.
My voltage range is (0-3.5)V and my current range is (0-0.5)A

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because shopping recommendations are off-topic.